# Querying nested path from list of strings in Elasticsearch using nest

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I know I can do a nested path search when I want to search for just one value using the following code:

```cs
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.memberships)
                .Query(q2 => q2
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Should(s2 => s2
                        .Match(m => m.Field("memberships.Id").Query("20334089"))))))))
```

That works fine. I am trying to do a query based off of a list of strings as the field values. I am using this TermAny function based off this previous answer and thought it may have worked with this for a nested path query:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377068/1451776

```cs
private static QueryContainer TermAny<T>(QueryContainerDescriptor<T> descriptor, Field field, object[] values) where T : class
{
    QueryContainer q = new QueryContainer();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        q |= descriptor.Term(t => t.Field(field).Value(value));
    }
    return q;
}
```

Let's say I have a list of Ids in a string array myIDSArry and I want to use that to search in a nested path field called memberships in elasticsearch. I have tried this

```cs
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.memberships)
                .Query(q2 => q2
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Should(s => TermAny(s, "memberships.Id", myIDSArry)))))))
```

However it comes back as 0 hits and I know there should be some in the results. Any ideas on how I can use this based off a list of strings to search?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer and am posting it in case others have the same question. Its pretty simple based off what I know in querying in elasticsearch, the word "keyword" I know is used sometimes. I fixed it by adding .keyword

```cs
.Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.memberships)
                .Query(q2 => q2
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Should(s => TermAny(s, "memberships.Id.keyword", myIDSArry)))))))
```