# C# NEST client for Elasticsearch search from array of strings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have documents like

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "description": "some description",
  "tags": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

How I can specify my query use C# Nest lib for find document by one Tag? For example, `q=hre`
and doc find
Try this, but its not work

```
q.Nested(nqd => nqd
                        .Path(x => x. tags)
                        .Query(qcd => qcd
                            .Bool(b => 
                                b.Should(s => 
                                    s.QueryString(x => 
                                        x.Fields(z => 
                                            z.Field(y => y.items))
                                            .Query(search))))))
```

Comment: Could you share your index mapping?

Comment: I hope this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374003/querying-array-of-strings-by-array-of-strings-in-elasticsearch-net