# How to search elastic data by array of string and string parameter by using IElasticClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository, nest

Since I am unfamiliar with the `ElasticSearch` concept, I used some code as a guide to build my general elastic search `NEST` query by injected `IElasticClient` . that is, is following

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEsDataWithSearchParameterAsync<T>(string indexName, string searchParameter) where T : class
        {
            var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(s => s
                                 .Index(indexName)
                                 .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                                 .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(searchParameter + "*")))
                                  ).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var documents = searchResponse.Documents;
            return documents;
        }
```

I've read through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html) link, but it's hard to grasp. I'm looking for video lessons for comprehensive learning similar to those offered by Udemy, but I haven't been successful in finding any as of now.

So I need to write a generic method for get list of properties by array of string and string value, like

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEsDataByArrayOfValuesWithFieldNameAndParameterAsync<T>(string indexName,string searchParameter,string field, string[] values) where T : class
    {
        var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(s => s
                             .Index(indexName)
                             .Query(q=>q.Term("market", searchParameter))
                             .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Should(s => TermAny(s, field, values))))
        );

        var documents = searchResponse.Documents;
        return documents;
    }

    private static QueryContainer TermAny<T>(QueryContainerDescriptor<T> descriptor, Field field, object[] values) where T : class
    {
        QueryContainer q = new QueryContainer();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            q |= descriptor.Term(t => t.Field(field).Value(value));
        }
        return q;
    }
```

As referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374003/querying-array-of-strings-by-array-of-strings-in-elasticsearch-net) link I updated my code but not getting any data,
but by DSL queried its getting 2 records

```
query: {query_string: {query: "(clusterId: "/SE_003/","/SE_004/") AND (market:SE)"}}
query_string: {query: "(clusterId: "/SE_003/","/SE_004/") AND (market:SE)"}
query: "(clusterId: \"/SE_003/\",\"/SE_004/\") AND (market:SE)"
```

and also tried by

```
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(s => s
             .Index(indexName)
             //.Query(q=>q.Bool(b=>b.Should(s=>
             //    s.Match(qs => qs.Field("market").Query(searchParameter)),
             //    s.Query(sq => sq.Terms(c=>c.Field(field).Terms<string>(values)))
             //    )))
             .Query(q => q.Match(qs => qs.Field("market").Query(searchParameter)))
             .Query(q => q.Terms(c => c.Field(field).Terms<string>(values)))
             );
```

which is also getting null record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(s => s
                             .Index(indexName)
                             .From(0)
                             .Size(10000)
                             .Query(q =>
                             q.QueryString(qs =>
                             qs.Query($"({firstField}:{firstFieldValue}) {operatorType} ({secondField}:{secondFieldValue})")))
                             .Sort(s => s.Ascending(SortLinks))
                             ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```